# How to set an notification for a day before the selected date on android

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, alarm

I get the date values from MySQL through JSONArray. Then it is displayed in a textview and when on click the set alarm button it will set the notification on that date and time. All worked fine.

But i need to set the alarm before the selected date and before 5mins. 
How can i set it in JAVA Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It should help you to schedule operations.

Comment: If the date is march 1st and the date before will be feb 28th. will it work if i minus 1 from the date? like leap years and all will it work accordingly?